# Query Finding Duplicate Values in one table

Tags: mysql

Im trying to write a Query that compares 5 user ids that keyed in different emails and then if it finds two different user ids that keyed in the same email, it will show a single column with the email they used, and 5 other columns showing the number of times it was used for both users, and 0 for the other 3 users who didn't use it in a single table. here's an example:

input:

```
    IDs|Email              
    U1 |test@email        
    U2 |test1@email
    U1 |test1@email
    U3 |test1@email
    U4 |test@email
    U1 |test1@email
```

Output:

```
    Email        | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 | ID5
    test@email   |  1  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0
    test1@email  |  2  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  0
```

ive been trying to do it and tried all possible options like GROUP BY and self-JOIN but its not running the query. 
Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation` to `pivot` your results:

```
select email, 
       sum(case when ids = 'U1' then 1 else 0 end) as Id1,
       sum(case when ids = 'U2' then 1 else 0 end) as Id2,
       sum(case when ids = 'U3' then 1 else 0 end) as Id3,
       sum(case when ids = 'U4' then 1 else 0 end) as Id4,
       sum(case when ids = 'U5' then 1 else 0 end) as Id5
from yourtable
group by email
```

---

Since you are using `mysql`, you could also use the following shorter version:

```
select email, 
       sum(ids = 'U1') as Id1,
       sum(ids = 'U2') as Id2,
       sum(ids = 'U3') as Id3,
       sum(ids = 'U4') as Id4,
       sum(ids = 'U5') as Id5
from yourtable
group by email
```

Comment: Thank you so much for these answers @sgeddes ! I got closer to figuring out the rest of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This query should do:

```
select
  email,
  sum(case ids = 'U1' then 1 end) as id1,
  sum(case ids = 'U2' then 1 end) as id2,
  sum(case ids = 'U3' then 1 end) as id3,
  sum(case ids = 'U4' then 1 end) as id4,
  sum(case ids = 'U5' then 1 end) as id5
from my_table
group by email
```